# Use find_if and remove_if in a vector of struct C++

Tags: c++, lambda

I have a program, with a struct filled with information of different persons. And a vector persons, with it.

```
struct Person
{
    std::string fName;
    std::string lName;
    float  length;
    std::string nSignature;

    bool operator==(const Person& m) const {
        return ((m.fName == fName) && (m.lName == lName) && (m.length == length) && (m.nSignature == nSignature));
    }
};
```

Now what I am trying to do is, to use find_if and search for a nSignature that is in the struct. And if it is, to print out all the elements that are connected to it.

Example:

Firstname: John
Surname: Doe
Length: 1,78m
Signature: johdoe

Now if i search for johdoe, and it is found, i want to print out all the details (like abow) that are connected to signature johdoe.

But that is not the main problem right now, the main problem is that i cant get my search to work.

```
void searchName(vector<Person> &persons)
{
    string nameToFind;
    cout << "Search" << flush;
    cin >> nameToFind;

    auto findIt = find_if(persons.begin(), persons.end(), [&nameToFind](Person& person) {
        return person.nSignature == nameToFind;
    });

    if (findIt != persons.end()) 
        cout << findIt << endl;

}
```

It doesn't find anything, and doesn't return anything either.

Have I misunderstood find_if and the use of operators?

Comment: *the main problem is that i cant get my search to work.* Are you seeing compile time errors or run time errors? Which lines seems to be the problem?

Comment: The one thing that comes to mind is that you are entering a name with spaces, the >> operator will only grab the first 'word'. Use std::getline() if you need to deal with something like that. Also, make sure the name is actually what you think it is. Your find_if appears okay,

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your code is incomplete; in particular, it seems to be missing a `main()` function and at least one `#include`.   Additionally, to make your symptoms reproducible, it's better to pass `nameToFind` as an additional parameter to the function, rather than passing it via `std::cin`.  Please [edit] your code so it's a [mcve] of your problem, then we can try to reproduce and solve it. You should also read [ask].

Comment: Don't you want `cout << *findIt << endl`? You are sending an iterator to cout and honestly I don't know if that works. But without seeing how you set up the vector, we're just guessing. The lambda looks OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code should work, and will find the first right signature.

The only problem is you need dereference the iterator, and also overload the operator `<<` for your class.

```
cout << *findIt << endl;
```

or if you do not want to overload, you can cout what you want explicitly

```
cout << findIt->fName << " " << findIt->lName  << endl;
```

overload like such, then it will work well.

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Person& p)  
{  
    os << p.fName << " " << p.lName << " " << p.length << " " << p.nSignature << endl;
    return os;  
}
```

Comment: This is something I should do in the same function? Didn't know i had to overload it, even though it went red, the first <<, i couldnt really understand why.

Comment: what do you want to print of the Person object. That's why you need to overload. Or you can also just write cout << findIt->nSignature << endl; without the need to overload.

Comment: Because you are couting `findIt`, which is an iterator. By define, it does not know how to `operator <<`(unless you overload for iterator). But in general, it is better to overload `<<` for the struct, other than the iterator. I suppose you want to `cout` the data of the matched person .

Comment: got these errors


Error C2601 'operator <<': local function definitions are illegal  
Error C2679 binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<_Ty>>>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)  
Error (active) E0065 expected a ';'

Comment: It worked like a charm. Thank you, espacially for explaining why this is needed. Wish my teacher was like this.